# Couldn't get string in array by strtok function in c

Tags: c, strtok

I am going to take data from csv file but when I use strtok function to split the data by comma separation here when I put splitted strings in array . It couldn't show real output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
char *name[20];



int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("meetingData.csv", "r");
    if (!fp)
        printf("Can't open file\n");

    else {
        int count;
        char buffer[1024];

        while (fgets(buffer,1024, fp)) {
            char *value = strtok(buffer, ", ");
            printf("%s\n",value);
            int x = 0;
            while (value != NULL) {
                if (x == 0) {
                    name[i] = value;
                    printf("name[%d]is  %s", i, name[i]);
                    i = i + 1;
                    x++;
                } else if (x == 1) {
                    printf("\n");
                    x++;
                } else {
                    //time[j] = j+'0';
                    //  printf("%s",value);
                    //printf("%d\n",x);
                    x++;
                    j++;

                }
                value = strtok(NULL, ",");
               // printf("%d\n", x);
            }


        }
        for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
            printf("%s\n", name[k]);
          //  printf("%s\n", time[k]);
      }
        fclose(fp);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Here you can see my outputs   they show the data with array

but when I print in a loop the last element will print for  whole array index

```
/home/karan/untitled14/cmake-build-debug/untitled14
Ashley_Parry
name[0]is  Ashley_Parry
Namal_Perera
name[1]is  Namal_Perera
Namal_Perera
name[2]is  Namal_Perera
Prabath_Silva
name[3]is  Prabath_Silva
Bethany_William
name[4]is  Bethany_William
Ashley_Parry
name[5]is  Ashley_Parry
Namal_Perera
name[6]is  Namal_Perera
Aaliya_Bruce
name[7]is  Aaliya_Bruce
Aaliya_Bruce
name[8]is  Aaliya_Bruce
Prabath_Silva
name[9]is  Prabath_Silva
Waruni_Fernando
name[10]is  Waruni_Fernando
Raul_Oliver
name[11]is  Raul_Oliver
Aaliya_Bruce
name[12]is  Aaliya_Bruce
Dr_Rajitha_Karunarathna
name[13]is  Dr_Rajitha_Karunarathna
Raul_Oliver
name[14]is  Raul_Oliver
Jasper_Jensen
name[15]is  Jasper_Jensen
Jasper_Jensen
name[16]is  Jasper_Jensen
Namal_Perera
name[17]is  Namal_Perera
Chamira_Perera
name[18]is  Chamira_Perera
Wasana_Tennekoon
name[19]is  Wasana_Tennekoon
Dr_Kamal_Jayasooriya
name[20]is  Dr_Kamal_Jayasooriya
Raul_Oliver
name[21]is  Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
Raul_Oliver
```

Comment: runing the posted code through the `gcc` compiler results in:  *untitled.c:60:3: warning: ‘count’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]*  when compiling,  always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`. at a minimum use the options: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtok` does not allocate any memory, it just returns pointers into the memory you use. In here you have one single `buffer` into which you read data and then tokenize it. This means every time the first item returned the pointer  is the same as `buffer` and every time you read new data it overwrites the old.

You’ll need to allocate memory for the data you want to store (perhaps with `strdup`) and then manage freeing it when not needed.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. eliminates duplicate variables
4. eliminates duplicate printing
5. uses meaningful names for variables
6. demonstrates how to report an error from 'fopen()'
7. demonstrates consistent horizontal spacing (for readability)
8. demonstrates a method for vertical spacing (for readability)
9. properly extracts pointers to the CSV names
10. properly minimizes the scope of variables
11. properly counts the number of CSV names
12. does not close the input file until all lines are read/processed

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_LEN 1024
#define MAX_CSV 20

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( "meetingData.csv", "r" );
    if (!fp)
    {
        //printf("Can't open file\n");
        perror( "fopen to read meetingData,csv failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    char buffer[ BUF_LEN ];
    while ( fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp ) ) 
    {
        int count=0;
        char *name[ MAX_CSV ] = {NULL};
        
        char *value = strtok( buffer, ", " );
        while ( count < MAX_CSV && value != NULL ) 
        {
            name[ count ] = value;
            printf("name[%d] is  %s", count, name[ count ]);
            count++;
            
            value = strtok( NULL, "," );
        }
    }

    fclose( fp );
    return 0;
}
```